# Parameterize Azure Blob Storage Linked Service in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I would like to create an Azure Data Factory pipeline that copies a file to multiple storage accounts. My plan was to define the storage account connection info in a pipeline parameter as an array and use the ForEach activity to loop over each of the objects in the array passing the connection info to another pipeline.

```
    [
  {
    "destinationBlob": {
      "connectionString": "Conn1"
    }
  },
  {
    "destinationBlob": {
      "connectionString": "Conn2"
    }
  },
  {
    "destinationBlob": {
      "connectionString": "Conn3"
    }
  }
]
```

My question is, is it possible to parameterize the connection to an Azure Blob Storage Linked Service?

Comment: Microsoft accepted that adding parameters via JSON is a valid way of doing it. See my comment on azure docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services#supported-data-stores), ADF parameterization of Linked Service does not support azure blob storage.

[image]

So,you could copy the specific file into destinations apart only so far.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the document you shared I see: “For all other data stores, you can parameterize the linked service by selecting the Code icon on the Connections tab and using the JSON editor.” I’ll give that a try and see what happens...

Comment: There's a chance that would work, I've used keyvault configurations for fields that are not keyvault configurable from the UI using the code view. I copy pasted configurations based from other linked services and that did the job.

Comment: Update: I tried to parameterize the azure storage connection string using the JSON editor but was unsuccessful. I had to create a new Copy activity, linked service, and dataset for each storage destination... here is a link to voice support for parameterization https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/36471121-parametrize-blob-storage-linked-services-with-dyna

Comment: As suggested in my answer below, there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This can actually be done. Sample JSON:

```
{
    "name": "DataLakeBlob",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "StorageAccountEndpoint": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "https://testblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net"
            }
        },
        "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
            "serviceEndpoint": "@{linkedService().StorageAccountEndpoint}"
        },
        "description": "Test Description"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This was acknowledged by Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services#

For those looking for SAS token parameterization, you could use following JSON.
Be sure to check the checkbox like in screenshot for the JSON to apply.
[image]

```
{
  "type":"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
  "properties":{
  "parameters": {
        "StorageAccountEndpoint": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "https://<<yourstorageaccountname>>.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlac&se=2019-10-20T16:33:57Z&st=2019-09-20T08:33:57Z&spr=https&sig=lDrBjD%2BjM2T1XjRW997VPMqDp99ZxVoReyRK0VEX7zQ%3D"
        }
    },
    "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
    "typeProperties": {
        "sasUri": "@{linkedService().StorageAccountEndpoint}"
    }

}}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this one really works? It uses the 'defaultValue' and never uses the actual value of 'StorageAccountEndpoint'. 'StorageAccountEndpoint' is always empty and if you remove the 'defaultValue' you'll run into an error during runtime.

Comment: Yes it does. I'm passing actual values in run time via trigger

Comment: @DhruvJoshi, could you please show how do you pass the StorageAccountEndpoint value via trigger?

Comment: create a pipeline which accepts parameter from trigger, and has data sets which accepts parameter from pipeline and parameterized linked services which get supplied by data sets. There you go. Let me know if this did not help.